# Bootstrap Navbar toggle button not appearing when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the code I just started working on. The Navbar toggle button, which appears at low width screen is not working. When clicked, it's color changes a bit, bit the drop down nav is not appearing. Tried comparing it with the Navbar example in getboostrap.com, still no luck. Is it the issue in the Nav code? or have I placed the JS and CSS files in the wrong order? Help me fix this please.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-nav-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Pico</a> 
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap js required jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jQuery before Bootstrap like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jQuery reference before Bootstrap.min.js